# Trying to add names to a list and send to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I am working on a simple webpage with a script. There is a form in which you can enter a name, and then submit the form. Upon submitting, the script should read the value, push the name to an array, and add the string to the HTML paragraph right below it. Each time you submit a new name, the array and the displayed paragraph should get longer. However, when I press submit, the new name flashes up on the HTML paragraph for a brief moment before the page resets to it's starting setup. What is wrong with my code here?

```html
<body>
  <div id="infoDiv">
    <form href="JavaScript:void(0)" onSubmit="appendName();">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter names (no duplicates):</legend>
        <input type="text" id="guestName"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add name to guestlist"><br><br>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p id="guest_roster">Current list:<br>Empty</p>

    <script>
      var guestNames = [];
      var guestList = "Current list:<br>";

      function appendName() {
        var latestGuest = document.getElementById("guestName").value;
        guestNames = guestNames.push(latestGuest);
        guestList = guestList + latestGuest + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("guest_roster").innerHTML = guestList;
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `event.preventDefault();` to your onSubmit function.

Also when you're pushing to an array just use `guestNames.push(latestGuest);` no need to use `guestNames = guestNames.push(latestGuest);`

Working snippet:

```html
<body>
  <div id="infoDiv">
    <form href="JavaScript:void(0)" onSubmit="appendName(event);">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter names (no duplicates):</legend>
        <input type="text" id="guestName"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add name to guestlist"><br><br>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p id="guest_roster">Current list:<br>Empty</p>

    <script>
      var guestNames = [];
      var guestList = "Current list:<br>";

      function appendName() {
      event.preventDefault();
        var latestGuest = document.getElementById("guestName").value;
        guestNames.push(latestGuest);
        guestList = guestList + latestGuest + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("guest_roster").innerHTML = guestList;
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. What exactly is "event.preventDefault();" preventing? I added in the "JavaScript:void(0)" in order to prevent a page refresh, but it seems that may not have been effective or necessary.

Comment: Im not 100% sure why but I know its because you're setting the `href="JavaScript:void(0)"`If you want to prevent form submit with it use `action="JavaScript:void(0)"`. However I would avoid `"JavaScript:void(0)"` altogether.  event.preventDefault essentially stops event propagation. It [tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 1):

As @cb64 said, you have to pass the `event` and call `event.preventDefault()`.
Here are a few suggestions though.

- Prefer to use `let/const` to using `var` which declares your variables globally
- Erase the field after clicking the button by setting its value to `''`.
- Do not set your array to the return of `Array.push()`, simply call `push`, it is a mutating operation, your array will be updated.
- Instead of appending the names to a string, simply join the array using `<br>`.
- Wrap your `Empty` in your HTML by a `<span>` and set the `innnerHTML` of this element instead of setting the whole paragraph so you don't have to rewrite `Current list:`.

```html
<body>
  <div id="infoDiv">
    <form href="JavaScript:void(0)" onSubmit="appendName(event);">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter names (no duplicates):</legend>
        <input type="text" id="guestName"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add name to guestlist"><br><br>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p>Current list:<br><span id="guest_roster">Empty</span></p>

    <script>
      const guestNames = [];

      function appendName(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const guestName = document.getElementById('guestName');
        const latestGuest = guestName.value;
        guestName.value = '';
        guestNames.push(latestGuest);
        document.getElementById('guest_roster').innerHTML = guestNames.join('<br>');
      }
    </script>
</body>
```